# Evaluate sympy expression from an array of values

Tags: python, scipy, sympy

I'm experimenting with sympy and I've hit upon an issue I can't work out.

Using scipy I can write an expression and evaluate it for an array of x values as follows:

```
import scipy
xvals = scipy.arange(-100,100,0.1)
f = lambda x: x**2
f(xvals)
```

Using sympy I can write the same expression as follows:

```
import sympy
x = sympy.symbols('x')
g = x**2
```

I can evaluate this expression for a single value by doing the following:

```
g.evalf(subs={x:10})
```

However I can't work out how to evaluate it for an array of x values, like I did with scipy. How would I do this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

First of all, at the moment SymPy does not guarantee support for numpy arrays which is what you want in this case. Check this bug report http://code.google.com/p/sympy/issues/detail?id=537

Second, If you want to evaluate something numerically for *many* values SymPy is not the best choice (it is a symbolic library after all). Use numpy and scipy.

However, a valid reason to evaluate something numerically will be that deriving the expression to be evaluated was hard so you derive it in SymPy and then evaluate it in NumPy/SciPy/C/Fortran. To translate an expression to numpy just use

```
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify
func = lambdify(x, big_expression_containing_x,'numpy') # returns a numpy-ready function
numpy_array_of_results = func(numpy_array_of_arguments)
```

Check the docstring of lambdify for more details. Be aware that lambdify still has some issues and may need a rewrite.

And just as a side note, if you want to evaluate the expressions **really** many times, you can use the codegen/autowrap module from sympy in order to create fortran or C code that is wrapped and callable from python.

EDIT: An updates list of ways to do numerics in SymPy can be found on the wiki https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Philosophy-of-Numerics-and-Code-Generation-in-SymPy

Answer (score 9):

While [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10683911/321973) makes it clear that the OP was looking for *numerical* evaluation, I'll still point out that one can also have *symbolic* evaluation by using `symarray`:

```
import sympy
xs = sympy.symarray('x', 10)
f = lambda x: x**2
f(xs)
```

yields

```
array([x_0**2, x_1**2, x_2**2, x_3**2, x_4**2, x_5**2, x_6**2, x_7**2,
       x_8**2, x_9**2], dtype=object)
```

Note that this also uses a `numpy` array internally, but one filled with `sympy.Expr`essions.

Comment: But symarray doesn't attribute a numeric value to each x_i, so how would you evaluate the expression for the arange specfied in the question?

Comment: @fccoelho I'd use numpy to start with, or at least `lambdify` from the accepted answer. But if for some reason you really have an array of symbolic expressions, you'll probably have to use a list comprehension (or `for` loop). Maybe there is an easier way, but I never bothered with `symarray`s much. My answer is really only here as a sidenote

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it via numpy.vectorize.
I am using `x`, `g`, and `xvals` from the question body.

```
scalar_func = lambda xx: float(g.evalf(subs={x: xx}))
vector_func = numpy.vectorize(scalar_func)
vector_func(xvals) # returns a numpy array [10000.0, 9980.01, 9960.04, ...]
```

Answer (score -3):

try

```
import sympy
x = sympy.symbols('x')
f = lambda x: x**2
print [f(k) for k in range(4)]
```

or you can also try

```
g = x**2
print [g.subs(x,k) for k in range(4)]
```

Comment: Your first example is not using sympy in any way. The symbol that you define is not accessed in the lambda. Morever, the question was about numpy arrays and presumably all the special per-element operations supported by numpy. These are not features present in python's list (what you are actually using).