# What is the best way to convert a SymPy matrix to a numpy array/matrix

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, numpy, sympy

I am not sure if the approach I've been using in `sympy` to convert a `MutableDenseMatrix` to a `numpy.array` or `numpy.matrix` is a good current practice.

I have a symbolic matrix like:

```
g = sympy.Matrix( [[   x,  2*x,  3*x,  4*x,  5*x,  6*x,  7*x,  8*x,   9*x,  10*x],
                   [x**2, x**3, x**4, x**5, x**6, x**7, x**8, x**9, x**10, x**11]] )
```

and I am converting to a `numpy.array` doing:

```
g_func = lambda val: numpy.array( g.subs( {x:val} ).tolist(), dtype=float )
```

where I get an array for a given value of `x`.

Is there a better built-in solution in SymPy to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Most of this question is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678843/evaluate-sympy-expression-from-an-array-of-values/10683911#10683911 - I know it is not exactly the same question but it gives all that is necessary to know about numpy/sympy interoperability.

Comment: thank you! feel fee to prepare an answer, because I think this is the best approach for my case too...

Comment: Yes, use `lambdify` (I'm too lazy to write it up to an answer right now).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This answer is based on the advices from Krastanov and asmeurer. This little snippet uses [sympy.lambdify](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html):

```
from sympy import lambdify
from sympy.abc import x, y

g = sympy.Matrix([[   x,  2*x,  3*x,  4*x,  5*x,  6*x,  7*x,  8*x,   9*x,  10*x],
                  [y**2, y**3, y**4, y**5, y**6, y**7, y**8, y**9, y**10, y**11]])
s = (x, y)
g_func = lambdify(s, g, modules='numpy')
```

where `g` is your expression containing all symbols grouped in `s`.

If `modules='numpy'` is used the output of function `g_func` will be a `np.ndarray` object:

```
g_func(2, 3)
#array([[     2,      4,      6,      8,     10,     12,     14,     16,       18,     20],
#       [     9,     27,     81,    243,    729,   2187,   6561,  19683,    59049, 177147]])

g_func(2, y)
#array([[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20],
#       [y**2, y**3, y**4, y**5, y**6, y**7, y**8, y**9, y**10, y**11]], dtype=object)
```

If `modules='sympy'` the output is a `sympy.Matrix` object.

```
g_func = lambdify(vars, g, modules='sympy')
g_func(2, 3)
#Matrix([[2,  4,  6,   8,  10,   12,   14,    16,    18,     20],
#        [9, 27, 81, 243, 729, 2187, 6561, 19683, 59049, 177147]])

g_func(2, y)
#Matrix([[   2,    4,    6,    8,   10,   12,   14,   16,    18,    20],
#        [y**2, y**3, y**4, y**5, y**6, y**7, y**8, y**9, y**10, y**11]])
```

Answer (score 48):

This looks like the most straightforward:

```
np.array(g).astype(np.float64)
```

If you skip the astype method, numpy will create a matrix of type 'object', which won't work with common array operations.

Comment: It works. And np.array(g, dtype=np.float64) will not.

Answer (score 8):

```
 numpy.array(SympyMatrix.tolist()).astype(numpy.float64)
```

The native `tolist` method to makes the sympy matrix into something nestedly indexed

`numpy.array` can cast something nestedly indexed into arrays

`.astype(float64)` will cast numbers of the array into the default numpy float type, which will work with arbitrary numpy matrix manipulation functions.

As an additional note - it is worth mentioning that by casting to numpy you loose the ability to do matrix operations while keeping sympy variables and expressions along for the ride.

EDIT:
The point of my additional note, is that upon casting to numpy.array, you loose the ability to have a variable anywhere in your matrix. All your matrix elements must be numbers already before you cast or everything will break.

Answer (score 7):

From the [SymPy-0.7.6.1_mpmath_ matrix docs](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.6.1/modules/mpmath/matrices.html#other), the `tolist()` method exists:

> Finally, it is possible to convert a matrix to a nested list. This is very useful, as most Python libraries involving matrices or arrays (namely NumPy or SymPy) support this format:

```
B.tolist()
```

Comment: `mpmath.matrices.matrices.tolist()` returns a list of `mpmath.ctx_mp_python.mpf` so you will still need to cast it, but IMO this isn't what the OP is asking for, since they want a function that produces numpy arrays, which is what the accepted answer does.

Answer (score 6):

Sympy now provides the `sympy.matrix2numpy` function:

```py
sympy.matrix2numpy(g)
# array([[x, 2*x, 3*x, 4*x, 5*x, 6*x, 7*x, 8*x, 9*x, 10*x],
#       [x**2, x**3, x**4, x**5, x**6, x**7, x**8, x**9, x**10, x**11]],
#      dtype=object)
```

To perform substitution for a specific value of `x`:

```py
g_func = lambda val: sympy.matrix2numpy(g.subs(x, val), dtype=float)
g_func(1)
# array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10.],
#        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

This approach is particularly useful for converting a numeric Sympy matrix to a numpy array:

```
M = sympy.Matrix([[123,456],[789, 123]])
sympy.matrix2numpy(M, dtype=int)
# array([[123, 456],
#       [789, 123]])
```