# TypeError when using SymPy matrices for numpy.linalg.eig

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

The following code works just fine

```
import numpy.linalg as nplin
T = [[1,0],[0,1]]
nplin.eig(T)
```

which results in the output

```
(array([ 1.,  1.]), array([[ 1.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  1.]]))
```

But if I try to use a `Matrix` object from sympy,

```
import numpy.linalg as nplin
from sympy import Matrix
T = Matrix([[1,0],[0,1]])
nplin.eig(T)
```

I get the following error

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Even if I convert the SymPy Matrix object to a NumPy array,

```
import numpy.linalg as nplin
import numpy
from sympy import Matrix
T = numpy.array(Matrix([[1,0],[0,1]]))
nplin.eig(T)
```

I still get the same error. What seems to be the problem here ?

I am using `Python 2.7.9`, `NumPy 1.8.2`, and `SymPy 0.7.7dev`.

Comment: You have to convert the sympy matrix to a numpy array first. But this is not trivial. A simpe `np.array(sympy_matrix)` won't do. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17069864/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-a-sympy-matrix-to-a-numpy-array-matrix

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I did not know about this. This worked for me : `numpy.array(Matrix([[1,0],[0,1]]).tolist()).astype(numpy.float32)`. Which is based on one of the answers from the SO post.

Comment: Since, `numpy.linalg.eig` can handle lists, the following is sufficient `Matrix([[1,0],[0,1]]).tolist()`.