# Plotting the output of a function gives this error-TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: python, plot, sympy

I tried to plot the output of the defined function with respect to z. However the error TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' is shown. Please help.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import sympy as sp

a=1.48185562
b=0.57081914
c=-0.25098188
H0=70.32724312

z=np.linspace(0.0,1.5,100)

omega_m0=0.3

dlabel= 'w(z) vz z'

def func(z):    
    sp.var('z+1')
    H=((2/H0)*((b*(z+1)+c*(z+1)**0.5+2.0-a-b-c)*(1-0.5*a*(z+1)**(-0.5)) - ((z+1)-a*(z+1)**0.5-1.0+a)*(b+c*0.5*(z+1)**(-0.5)))/(b*(z+1)+c*(z+1)**0.5+2.0-a-b-c)**2)**(-1) 
    return ((2*(z+1)/3)*(sp.diff(sp.log(H)))-1)/(1-(H/H0)**2*omega_m0*(z+1)**3)

wz=func(z)

plt.plot(z,wz)
plt.xlabel('z')
plt.ylabel('w(z)')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you want to do with `sp.var('z+1')`... at least I hope you were not trying to create a variable named z+1. I got the code to run but I let you make sure it does what you want and complain if not :)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import sympy as sp

a=1.48185562
b=0.57081914
c=-0.25098188
H0=70.32724312

x=np.linspace(0.0,1.5,100)

omega_m0=0.3

dlabel= 'w(z) vz z'

sp.var('z')

def func(z):    
  H=((2/H0)*((b*(z+1)+c*(z+1)**0.5+2.0-a-b-c)*(1-0.5*a*(z+1)**(-0.5)) - ((z+1)-a*(z+1)**0.5-1.0+a)*(b+c*0.5*(z+1)**(-0.5)))/(b*(z+1)+c*(z+1)**0.5+2.0-a-b-c)**2)**(-1) 
  return ((2*(z+1)/3)*(sp.diff(sp.log(H)))-1)/(1-(H/H0)**2*omega_m0*(z+1)**3)

wz = [func(z).evalf(subs = {z : y}) for y in x]

plt.plot(x,wz)
plt.xlabel('z')
plt.ylabel('w(z)')
plt.show()
```

EDIT: in order to get `wz`, the following piece is much faster ( cf [Evaluate sympy expression from an array of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678843/evaluate-sympy-expression-from-an-array-of-values) ):

```
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify
func_np_ready = lambdify(z, func(z),'numpy') # returns a numpy-ready function
wz = func_np_ready(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be better off flagging your question with `sympy` - it's probably the behaviour of one of those functions that's causing the issue, and someone else might know all about it.

It's probably a good idea to split those really long formulas up into multi lines (at least while debugging) to help you track down the error. Also put in some prints etc.

I know it's not what you want to achieve but if I cut out the sympy (I don't have it installed!) and adjust the array lengths it plots without error:

```
    ...
    H=((2/H0)*((b*(z+1)+c*(z+1)**0.5+2.0-a-b-c)*(1-0.5*a*(z+1)**(-0.5)) - ((z+1)-a*(z+1)**0.5-1.0+a)*(b+c*0.5*(z+1)**(-0.5)))/(b*(z+1)+c*(z+1)**0.5+2.0-a-b-c)**2)**(-1) 
    return ((2*(z[:-1]+1)/3)*(np.diff(np.log(H)))-1)/(1-(H[:-1]/H0)**2*omega_m0*(z[:-1]+1)**3)

wz=func(z)

plt.plot(z[:-1],wz)
```

[image]