# Plotting Sympy Result to Particular Solution of Differential Equation

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, sympy

So far I have managed to find the particular solution to this equation for any given mass and drag coefficient. I have not however found a way to plot the solution or even evaluate the solution for a specific point. I really want to find a way to plot the solution.

```
from sympy import *

m = float(raw_input('Mass:\n> '))
g = 9.8
k = float(raw_input('Drag Coefficient:\n> '))
f = Function('f')
f1 = g * m
t = Symbol('t')
v = Function('v')
equation = dsolve(f1 - k * v(t) - m * Derivative(v(t)), 0)
C1 = Symbol('C1')
C1_ic = solve(equation.rhs.subs({t:0}),C1)[0]
equation = equation.subs({C1:C1_ic})
```

Comment: Can you help me understand exactly what kind of plot you want to make? What are your x-axis and y-axis variables?

Comment: i want to plot velocity (v) versus time (t)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Import these libraries (seaborn just makes the plots pretty).

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
```

Then tack this onto the end. This will plot time, t, against velocity, v(t).

```
# make a numpy-ready function from the sympy results
func = lambdify(t, equation.rhs,'numpy')
xvals = np.arange(0,10,.1)
yvals = func(xvals)

# make figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,subplot_kw=dict(aspect='equal'))     
ax.plot(xvals, yvals)
ax.set_xlabel('t')
ax.set_ylabel('v(t)')
plt.show()
```

I get a plot like this for a mass of 2 and a drag coefficient of 2.
[image]

Comment: btw, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678843/evaluate-sympy-expression-from-an-array-of-values) is a helpful reference

Answer (score 7):

For completeness, you may also use Sympy's `plot`, which is probably more convenient if you want a "quick and dirty" plot.

```
plot(equation.rhs,(t,0,10))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, you want to represent the right hand side of your solution, here's one of the multiple ways to do it:

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = float(raw_input('Mass:\n> '))
g = 9.8
k = float(raw_input('Drag Coefficient:\n> '))
f = Function('f')
f1 = g * m
t = Symbol('t')
v = Function('v')
equation = dsolve(f1 - k * v(t) - m * Derivative(v(t)), 0)
C1 = Symbol('C1')
C1_ic = solve(equation.rhs.subs({t: 0}), C1)[0]
equation = equation.subs({C1: C1_ic})

t1 = np.arange(0.0, 50.0, 0.1)
y1 = [equation.subs({t: tt}).rhs for tt in t1]

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(t1, y1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: It's better to use lambdify to create a numpy function than to evaluate the function using subs and a list comprehension.